# Trying to implement the django-formset library but I am unable to get any of the buttons to work. They are completely non-responsive

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I am trying to utilize the django-formset library to create dynamic forms. However, I am unable to get any of the buttons to work (whether they're add/submit or add forms). The only error in the javascript console was the following:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
> at Object.i [as convertPseudoClasses] (http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/formset/js/chunk-KFPGMBXM.js:1:354)
> at http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/formset/js/django-formset.js:25:29909

This is my first time working with django, html, css, javascript, and jquery but as far as I could trace the issue, I thought it maybe had something to do with not loading the typescript implementation of the 'click' webelement based on this error. But I got stuck tracing the error and so I tried to simplify/isolate the issue by creating a new project and copying the examples in the documentation. I also though there could be a conflict or issue with one of my templates, another library, or with a javascript function...

...but I can't get even the simplest model/form button to work using the example in [Chapter 9 of the documentation](https://django-formset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model-form.html). So I'm wondering if there's something really basic I'm missing. The following example doesn't throw any errors in the browser console but results in the same dead button issue.

#models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=55, blank=True)
```

#forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

#views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, ListView
from django.utils.encoding import force_str
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from formset.views import EditCollectionView, FormCollectionView, FormView, FileUploadMixin, FormViewMixin

from .forms import *
from .models import *


class CustomerEditView(FormViewMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'testing/customer-edit.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('customer-list')
    extra_context = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if self.extra_context['add'] is False:
            return super().get_object(queryset)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if extra_data := self.get_extra_data():
            if extra_data.get('delete') is True:
                self.object.delete()
                success_url = self.get_success_url()
                response_data = {'success_url': force_str(success_url)} if success_url else {}
                return JsonResponse(response_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)


class CustomerListView(ListView):
    model = Customer

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

#urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', CustomerListView.as_view(), name='customer-list'),  # list view not handled here
    path('add/', CustomerEditView.as_view(extra_context={'add': True}),
         name='customer-add',
         ),
    path('<int:pk>/', CustomerEditView.as_view(extra_context={'add': False}),
         name='customer-edit',
         ),
]
```

#customer-edit.html:

```
{% load i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% load render_form from formsetify %}

<django-formset endpoint="{{ request.path }}" csrf-token="{{ csrf_token }}">
  {% render_form form %}
  {% if add %}
    <button type="button" click="submit({add: true}) -> proceed">{% trans "Add" %}</button>
  {% else %}
    <button type="button" click="submit({update: true}) -> proceed">{% trans "Update" %}</button>
    <button type="button" click="submit({delete: true}) -> proceed">{% trans "Delete" %}</button>
  {% endif %}

</django-formset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the library has some built-in JavaScript functions to submit the form as you can see in the `button` tag attribute `click`.

So, you just need to import / load those functions on your `template` as described in the library [`documentation`](https://django-formset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

customer-edit.html

```
{% load i18n %} 
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <script
      type="module"
      src="{% static 'formset/js/django-formset.js' %}"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I probably should have just posted my original problem as I did import those functions in my main project. If I'm extending a base template is it ok if I import in the head of base.html or should I be importing in the child template?

Comment: It is okay to import only on the `base.html`. But, if `button` actions are not working means that the functions are not being triggered. Which in you case makes sense because I do not see `{% extends 'base.html' %}` anywhere in your template file.